# Detect if an object allows creation of custom fields

Tags: fields, customization

I am building a package for custom field creation. I have noticed in some cases the following errors:

```
FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION:Cannot add custom fields to entity: AIRecordInsight
```

and

```
FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION:Cannot add custom fields to entity: AIInsightReason
```

Is there any way to use dynamic apex to find out the list of objects that support creation of custom fields rathen than running field creation script for every object and catching errors?

Answer (score 3):

[EntityDefinition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_entitydefinition.htm) object has an attribute `IsCustomizable` which tells if custom fields can be defined for the entity. Also `DandBCompany` should be manually excluded since it returns true but doesn't allow custom fields.